# Should apps on iPad Pro work just like on any other iPad

Tags: ios, ipad

iPad Pro resolution size is  2732‑by‑2048. iPad air 2 resolution is 2048‑by‑1536. So if an iOS game was built specifically for all iPad's from Apple, and the app is currently out, does it mean on the new resolution iPad Pro the game app will look like it doesn't fit on the screen?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR;**

It depends on the app.

**More explanation:**

Many apps that look fine on all iPhones and iPads are basically the same app. They are written that way to work on all resolutions. (It's a good programming practice not to assume anything about screen resolution of the device the program is run. It's not always possible though).

However, there is the possibility that some apps don't look good on iPad Pro because developers haven't tested their apps on it. For example, in a game, you may view more of the field.

Comment: or things get stretched... Which can become a problem if the app uses highly compressed textures to save space.

Comment: @jwenting You're right, but since OP only mentioned iPad Air 2 and iPad Pro and they have the same aspect ratio (4:3), I didn't mention stretching.

Comment: I mean stretching as in a 64x64 image getting displayed at 128x128 for example

Comment: I'm a game developer and the biggest image I included is the background images. The biggest device it was made to handle was the iPad Air 2 because up until today it's the biggest iPad. That's why I'm uncertain if it'll look like it fits in the newly larger resized iPad or will it look like half the space is empty.

Comment: @robb It's best to check your app with iPad Pro simulator in Xcode.